# Recursion- reversing String

Tags: java, string, recursion

I believe that I have a decent understanding of recursion (factorial etc), however in the following example in reversing a string I do not understand the line. Can someone please explain what it does?

```
return reverseString(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
```

Full Code from method:

```
public static String reverseString(String str){

            if(str.length()<2){
                System.out.println("reached Base case");
                return str;
            }

            return reverseString(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);


            }
```

Comment: What do you think it does? What does each part do?

Comment: Try to see what each method do by reading the doc and taking a paper to see how it works with a small String.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call `substring(1)` takes the first character off of the string.  That is fed into the recursive call, which reverse all but the last character.  Then, the first character is appended, completing the reversal.

Example:

```
reverseString("abc") =>
reverseString("bc") + 'a' =>
(reverseString("c") + 'b') + 'a' =>
("c" + 'b') + 'a' =>
"cb" + 'a' =>
"cba"
```

Comment: Nice way to map out the example, and quick too

Comment: Thank you, after the first 3 lines has the method reached its base case? Also, I am wondering how (reverseString("c") + 'b') + 'a' => works, I dont see how it also returns 'a' if 'a' has been already removed from the string in the previous call?

Comment: Yes, `reverseString("c")` is in a base case, so it return `"c"`.  Then the next call takes what the base case returns -- `"c"` -- and concatenates its first character, `'b'`, and winds up returning `"cb"`.  Then the original call takes what was returned -- `"cb"` -- and concatenates its first character, `'a'`, and winds up returning `"cba"`.

Answer (score 0):

It takes everything after the first character and calls the recursive function.  The first character is put at the end of the string.  This results in a reversal.

```
return reverse(Everything after the first) + the first
```

Comment: See the example of this in action in rgettman's response. +1 to him.

Answer (score 0):

```
return reverseString(str.substring(1)) + str.charAt(0);
```

For example, the String is `HelloWorld`
Then `"HelloWorld".substring(1)` returns `"elloWorld"`
and `"HelloWorld".charAt(0)` returns `"H"`

You take the first letter and add it to the end od the string. But before, you do it again with the first part. In the end, this algorithm reverses the string.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this string:

```
str = "Reverse";
```

The value of `str.substring(1)` is "everse".
The value of `str.charAt(0)` is "R".

I think you can take it from there if you understand recursion.

Answer (score 0):

It inefficiently reverses the string by placing each successive sub-string on the stack until it reaches a length less then 2; it then reverses the characters by popping those results off the stack and appending the first character to the sub-string. It is inefficient because Java includes the StringBuilder class and that has a [reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Try to think of reversing a string in this manner:

```
//reverse of a string can be expressed as the last character 
//plus the reverse of everything remaining. For example, if we had
//"food", you would have "d" + reverse("foo"), which is "d" + "oof"
//which gives you "doof". So:

reverse(str)    = str[str.length - 1] + reverse(str[0:str.length - 2]);
reverse(str[0]) = str[0] //reverse of a 1 character string is the character itself
```

So apply this to the string `abcd`:

You have:

```
reverse("abcd") = "d" + reverse("abc")
reverse("abc")  = "c" + reverse("ab")
reverse("ab")   = "b" + reverse("a")
reverse("a")    = "a";
```

Now when you substitute you have:

```
reverse("ab")   = "b" + "a" = "ba"
reverse("abc")  = "c" + "ba" = "cba"
reverse("abcd") = "d" + "cba" = "dcba"
```

Think about how you can write code that mimics this behavior.